# Change factor into time format

Tags: r

A column contains only time in H:M:S(e.g. 13:08:20)  but its in FACTOR format so now I want to change the FACTOR into POSIXct so that I can apply ceiling date() function on it.

I have tried these in some cases when I run its shows no error but then the columns whole contains NA values. :

```
x <- anytime(cam5$CaptureTime)
x <- hms(cam5$CaptureTime)
x <- hms(as.character(cam5$CaptureTime))
x <- as.POSIXct(cam5$CaptureTime)
x <- as.POSIXct(as.character(cam5$CaptureTime))
```

Comment: Convert factor to character before converting to time

Comment: An example of data please, use dput to generate it.

Comment: @RonakShah I tried this but this shows NA values in whole column.

Comment: @Rohit That also shows the NA values. I have mentioned the codes above, if you are talking something else then please let me know.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks the problem is solved with the function you have shown above. thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.POSIXct` and specify the `format`

```
as.POSIXct("13:08:20", format = "%T")
```

Or specifying it separately

```
as.POSIXct("13:08:20", format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

This would also work with `strptime`

```
strptime("13:08:20", format = "%T")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
hms("13:08:20")
```